# Ordering with either image or text after downloaded from Parse

Tags: ios, swift, image, uitableview, parse-platform

I have a tableView with three images in each cell which display all the images from my posts class.. So I download all the images then divide them by 3 when they're put in the cell!! So it doesn't show the same image 3 times in each cell when downloaded...

A bit confusing but If I show you my code you might understand how it works better!

But anyway what I'm trying to do now is the same but with the text, so in a cell depending on what's downloaded it will either show the images as normal or if they're text It will show text instead of the image!!

```
// HERE'S HOW I SORT THE 3 IMAGES WHEN DOWNLOADED (CellForRowAtIndexPath)

if post.dataType == 1 
{ 
for imageView in cell.threeImages { 
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "ImagePlaceHolder") 

if counter < posts.count{ 
imageView.hidden = false 
let imagePost = posts[counter++].image 
imagePost!.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in 
if error == nil { 
if let imageData = data { 
imageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData) 
} 

} 
} 
} else { 
imageView.hidden = true 
}



// AND HERE'S HOW I SORT THEM / DIVIDE THEM BY 3 SO THEY'RE NOT ALL THE SAME FOR EACH ROW.

func roundUp(value: Double) -> Int {
    if value == Double(Int(value)) {
        return Int(value)
    } else if value < 0 {
        return Int(value)
    } else {
        return Int(value) + 1
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{

        return = roundUp(Double(posts.count) / 3.0) 


}
```

Here is what it looks like now on the simulator, after downloading all the images and it is also downloading 1 text column from parse: [![enter image description here][1]][1]

Now after I tried this code here:

```
//IMAGES

    if post.dataType == 1 
    { 
    //Images 
    for imageView in cell.threeImages { 
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "ImagePlaceHolder") 

    if counter < posts.count{ 

    imageView.hidden = false 

    let imagePost = posts[counter++].image 
    imagePost!.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in 
    if error == nil { 
    if let imageData = data { 
    imageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData) 

//TEXT
    for textHide in cell.threeLabels{ 
    textHide.hidden = true 
    }}}} } else { 
    imageView.hidden = true 
    }
```

I get this result which is nearly there:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

But what I am actually after is something where the text can be mixed up with the images like so:

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

I have a feeling it could be to do with the DataType code, as it allows either all images or all text...So here the code for my Struct too!

```
truct PostStruct {
        var dataType : Int = 0 // 0 for text, 1 for picture
        var date : NSDate
        var username : NSString 
        var text : NSString?
        var title : NSString?
        var image : PFFile?
        var uuid : NSString
        var profileImage : PFFile
        var caption : NSString?


        init (dataTypeInit: Int, dateInit : NSDate, usernameInit: String, textInit: String, titleInit: String, uuidInit: String,profileImageInit: PFFile) {
            dataType        = dataTypeInit
            date            = dateInit
            username        = usernameInit
            text            = textInit
            title           = titleInit
            uuid            = uuidInit
            profileImage    = profileImageInit
        }

        init (dataTypeInit: Int, dateInit : NSDate, usernameInit: String, imageInit: PFFile, uuidInit: String, profileImageInit: PFFile, captionInit: String) {
            dataType        = dataTypeInit
            date            = dateInit
            username        = usernameInit
            image           = imageInit
            uuid            = uuidInit
            profileImage    = profileImageInit
            caption         = captionInit
        }
    }


    var posts : [PostStruct] = []
```

**UPDATE**

```
                for imageView in cell.threeImages {
                    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "ImagePlaceHolder")
                    for textView in cell.threeLabels {


                        let rowData = tableData[indexPath.row]

                for indexInRow in 0...2
                {
                    if indexInRow > rowData.posts.count
                    {
                        textView.hidden = true
                        imageView.hidden = true
                        // there are less posts for this row than the current index - so hide both the image and the text
                        // hide the imageView at position indexInRow
                        // hide the text view (label) at position indexInRow
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         let postt = rowData.posts[indexInRow]
                        // there is a post - check to see if it's text or an image
                        if postt.dataType == 1
                            // image type (replace this with an enumerator at some point)
                        {
                            postt.image!.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                                if error == nil {
                                    if let imageData = data {
                                        imageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)

                                        imageView.hidden = false
                                        textView.hidden = true

                                    }

                                }
                            }


                            // display the image in image at position indexInRow
                            // hide the text view (label) at position indexInRow
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            imageView.hidden = true
                            textView.hidden = false
                            textView.text = postt.text as? String
                            // hide the imageView at position indexInRow
                            // display the text view (label) at position indexInRow
                        }
                    }
                    }}
                }
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating things by using having to keep dividing by three - why not create the data for the tableview already split into rows of three?

You could have the `rowData` structure like this

```
struct rowData
{
    var posts : [PostStruct] = []
}
```

and store it in a class-level variable like this

```
var tableData : [rowData] = []
```

and then parse the data into that structure when you load it

```
// create an array of tableData, 
// where each element is of type rowData
// which has up to 3 `post` entries
// each of which is either an image or a text post
// the tableView methods are then based on tableData
var indexInRow = 0
for post in posts 
{
    if indexInRow == 0
    {
        // create a new rowData object
        tableData.append(rowData())
    }
    tableData[tableData.count - 1].posts.append(post)

    // using the modulo operator like this will return the remainder  of dividing by 3, so it will always be 0, 1, 2
    indexInRow = (indexInRow + 1) % 3
}
```

and then your tableView methods look something like this

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let rowData = tableData[indexPath.row]

    for indexInRow in 0...2
    {
        if indexInRow > rowData.posts.count
        {
            // there are less posts for this row than the current index - so hide both the image and the text
            // hide the imageView at position indexInRow
            // hide the text view (label) at position indexInRow
        }
        else
        {
            // there is a post - check to see if it's text or an image

            // UPDATE
            let post = rowData.posts[indexInRow]
            // UPDATE

            if post.dataType == 0 // image type (replace this with an enumerator at some point)
            {
                // display the image in image at position indexInRow
                // hide the text view (label) at position indexInRow
            }
            else
            {
                // hide the imageView at position indexInRow
                // display the text view (label) at position indexInRow
            }
        }
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return tableData.count
}
```

Comment: Nearly got it working, just an issue I'm trying to figure out with the ordering..Everything is repeated 3 times for each row...I posted you a message

Comment: @Jack update the answer - just a bit to load each 'post' in turn from 'rowData'

Comment: I'm getting rowData.type has no subscript members

Comment: Ok, so far it's loading but all the cell's images change when scrolling and there's no order some duplicate also and you cannot see the text strangely! I have posted the cellForRow above in my question

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has something do with how the indexInRow is set up in the query. As if it's not perfectly divisible by 3 I also get array out of index...